# Is this the best way for the below needed Ruby application? + [Help in Arrays]

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Please advise if the code is correct or there is a better version and also how to sort the Array in descending orders & the output to be like that:

> A program that takes a user’s input, then builds a hash from that input. Each key in the hash will be a word from the user; each value will be the number of times that word occurs. For example, if our program gets the string “the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain,”

```
print "What is the sentence that needs to be analysed? "
sentence = gets.chomp
#puts sentence

#Text to Array 
my_array = sentence.split


#Create the Hash 

word_frequency = Hash.new(0)
#Iterate through the given array in the built Hash 
my_array.each { |word|
   word_frequency[word] += 1
}
 
puts word_frequency
```

Needed Output to be if we run the code:

> I love coding to the moon and love web coding

```
Love 2
coding 2 
I 1
to 1 
..... etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sentence = "Is this the best way for the below needed Ruby application?"

sentence.split.tally.sort_by { |_word, count| - count }.to_h

# => {"the"=>2, "Is"=>1, "this"=>1, "best"=>1, "way"=>1, "for"=>1, "below"=>1, "needed"=>1, "Ruby"=>1, "application?"=>1}
```

Firstly tokenize sentence to words array, than `tally` makes hash where key is word and value is count, than sort descending

You can also sort like this

```
sentence.split.tally.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
```

Also you can use unified case, for example with `String#upcase` method and to avoid capturing punctuation it's possible to use `String#scan` method

```
sentence.upcase.scan(/[[:word:]-]+/).tally.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
```

Comment: I am sorry bro as I still learning and I couldn't use tally and sort isn't reached yet, can i make amends using the below code 
```
print "What is the sentence that needs to be analysed? "
sentence = gets.chomp
#puts sentence

#Text to Array 
my_array = sentence.split


#Create the Hash 
word_frequency = Hash.new(0)
my_array.each { |word, count|
   word_frequency[word] += 1 
   word_frequency[word].sortby.{ |word, count| - count }
}
 
puts word_frequency
```

Comment: You can use something like this `words = "I am sorry bro as I still learning".split; word_frequency = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, hash| hash[word] += 1 }`

Comment: You may wish to first downcase and then use `sentence.scan(/]w+/)` rather than `sentence.split` to avoid capturing punctuation (plucking `"application"` rather than `"application?"` for example).

Answer (score 0):

After many trails & @mechnicov I had reached the below and hope to hear reviews:

```
print 'What is the sentence that needs to be analysed? '
sentence = gets.chomp

# Convert Text to Array:
my_array = sentence.split

# Create the Hash called histogram
histogram = Hash.new(0) # zero added as a counter for iterate through word and add on it if exist

my_array.each do |word|
  histogram[word] += 1
end

# Sort descending by values
sorted_histogram = histogram.sort_by { |_k, v| v }.reverse

#Print final output: 
sorted_histogram.each do |_word, _count|
  puts _word + ' ' + _count.to_s
end
```

Comment: [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) was added to the Ruby core to avoid the need for your statements `histogram = ....` and `my_array.each...end`. As @mechnicov points out, you can shorten `sort_by { |_k, v| v }` to `sort_by(&:last)`.

Comment: Underscores are only to unused variables